# Why can't I play cards on another challenge?

Tags: storium

In a Storium game I am playing in I made a move in a scene against a challenge and now when I go to "make another move" I can not choose a challenge card or play any cards of any kind.

In particular the challenge had 1 out of 4 cards met with uncertain. I played two neutral cards and a strength card, completing the challenge and winning control of the story.

Is there some kind of limit to the number of challenges a player can interact with or if a player completes 1 challenge and wins control of the story can they not complete another challenge?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Each player can only play 3 cards in a scene**

Once a player has played up to their maximum cards (through any number of moves) they are unable to mechanically influence the story any more. This stops 1 player from overwhelming the rest and makes challenge solving have to be cooperative.

> Hi! Each player can only play a maximum of 3 cards per scene. This keeps one player from “running away with the scene”. I’m guessing you’ve already played 3 cards in the current scene.
>
> BTW, the system won’t let the narrator play more challenge points than the players have cards to address them. So it’s impossible to create a situation where the scene’s challenges can’t be met. It’s just that every player has to contribute. - [Storium Support](http://storium.uservoice.com/forums/211322-general/suggestions/5781345-can-t-play-cards-on-a-challenge)

Answer (score 2):

There is a limit of three cards per scene. As you mentioned you already used 2 Neutral cards, and 1 Strength card. Exhausting your pool of cards.

Source: [Storium FAQ](https://storium.com/how-to-play/making-moves#playing-cards)

> You can play a maximum of three cards per scene. Storium keeps track of this, as well.